# Java Web Programming with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

hi all I'm trying to create a registration servlet for my java web site but am getting this error which I don't understand because there is nothing on line 1.

`Error.com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '',)' at line 1`

here is my code for the servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;


import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreateTutor
 */
@WebServlet("/CreateTutor")
public class CreateTutor extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CreateTutor() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String uniid = ""; 
    private String name = ""; 
    private String password = ""; 
    private String email = ""; 
    private int access_level = 3;

    public void init() {
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded"); 
      } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString()); 
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Get request*/ 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
  ServletException,IOException {  
      sendPageHeader(response); 
      sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
      sendPageFooter(response); 
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Post request*/ 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      sendPageHeader(response); 

      uniid = request.getParameter("uniid"); 
      name = request.getParameter("name"); 
      password = request.getParameter("password"); 
      email = request.getParameter("email");


      boolean error = false; 
      String message = null; 
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = 
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("got connection"); 

        Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

        String sql = "SELECT name FROM user" + 
          " WHERE name='" + name + "'"; 
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql); 
        if (rs.next()) {
          rs.close(); 
          message = "The user name <B>" + name + 
            "</B> has been taken. Please select another name."; 
          error = true; 
        } 
        else {
          rs.close(); 
          sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
            " '" +  name + "'," + 
            " '" +  password + "'," + 
            " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)"; 
          int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
          if (i==1) {
            message = "Successfully added one user."; 
          } 
        } 
          s.close(); 
          con.close(); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        if (message!=null) {
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
          out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
          out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
        } 
        if (error==true) 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, true); 
        else 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
        sendPageFooter(response); 
      } 

      /** 
       * Send the HTML page header, including the title 
       * and the <BODY> tag 
       */ 
      private void sendPageHeader(HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html"); 
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("<HTML>"); 
        out.println("<HEAD>"); 
        out.println("<TITLE>Registration Page</TITLE>"); 
        out.println("</HEAD>"); 
        out.println("<BODY>"); 
        out.println("<CENTER>"); 
      } 

      /** 
       * Send the HTML page footer, i.e. the </BODY> 
       * and the </HTML> 
       */ 
      private void sendPageFooter(HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("</CENTER>"); 
        out.println("</BODY>"); 
        out.println("</HTML>"); 
      }   
      /**Send the form where the user can type in 
       * the details for a new user 
       */ 
      private void sendRegistrationForm(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, boolean displayPreviousValues) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("<BR><H2>Registration Page</H2>"); 
        out.println("<BR>Please enter the user details."); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
        out.println("<BR><FORM METHOD=POST>"); 
        out.println("<TABLE>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Uni Id</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=uniid"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + uniid + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Name</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=name"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + name + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Password</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=PASSWORD Name=password"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + password + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Email</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=email");
        out.println("></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");
        out.println("<TR>");
        out.println("<TD>Access Level</TD>");
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=int Name=access_level");
        out.println("></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");
        if (displayPreviousValues) 
        out.print(" VALUE=\"" + password + "\""); 
        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>");

        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=RESET></TD>"); 
        out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("</TABLE>"); 
        out.println("</FORM>"); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
            " '" +  name + "'," + 
            " '" +  password + "'," + 
            " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)";
```

Change to: -

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
               " '"  +  name + "'," + 
               " '"  +  password + "'," + 
               " '"  + email + "','" + access_level + "')";
```

You missed the trailing comma after your query..

Comment: Down-Voter, I missed to remove the trailing comma from the end, but I did it now.. You can toggle your vote..

Comment: still getting an error Error.com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

Comment: Down-Voter can you toggle your vote, after I changed my post??

Answer (score 3):

The error is obvious: You have a syntax error in the SQL you're sending to MySQL.  Try printing out what you send and it'll be easier to see than reading it in the code.

But more importantly - don't do this.

1. You should be using PreparedStatement and binding your input
   variables.
2. You should be using a JNDI connection pool.
3. You should not be hardwiring your connection details - not once, but twice!
4. You code HTML into a servlet.  Better to use JSPs with JSTL.
5. You don't validate your input.  It's a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

That's enough for now.

Comment: its a university assignment that has requirements, jstl isn't allowed and we haven't been shown PreparedStatement.

Comment: OK, but you'll want to recognize these ideas when the day comes.  Besides, why must the truly curious student wait to be shown?  All you'd have to do is navigate to the javadocs, see what the difference is, and incorporate it into your implementation.  Your professor might be impressed by the research you'll do on SQL injection.  I would be if I were your professor.  Too much rote; too much "I only did what I was told."  Consider this answer your lecture.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma `,` in your select statement, instead of:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
            " '" +  name + "'," + 
            " '" +  password + "'," + 
            " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)"; 

                                                  /|\
                         this ----------------------
```

It should be

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
            " '" +  name + "'," + 
            " '" +  password + "'," + 
            " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "')";
```

I didn't know Java, but you should use [***prepared statements***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) or any other way in java to sanitize your data that let you specify the parameters instead of write the inputs' values directly in the sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problematic line is this:

```
"INSERT INTO user" + 
        " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
        " VALUES" + 
        " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
        " '" +  name + "'," + 
        " '" +  password + "'," + 
        " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)
```

please note the trailing comma at the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

you missed single quote & and have exra comma in

`" '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)";`  in you code.

it should be  `" '" + email + "','" + access_level + "')";`

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra comma at the end of your query:
 change the below

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
                " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
                " VALUES" + 
                " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
                " '" +  name + "'," + 
                " '" +  password + "'," + 
                " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "',)";
```

TO:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user" + 
            " (uniid, name, password, email, access_level)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  uniid + "'," + 
            " '" +  name + "'," + 
            " '" +  password + "'," + 
            " '" + email + "'," + access_level + "')";
```

i strongly recomment you to use [Prepared statement API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) .

Answer (score 0):

it's line 1 of the SQL request, not of the java program. Make your program print the request to the console, and debug it from there.